# Simple explanation of the Ankerl fast exponent algorithm

Tags: c++, optimization, exp

Recently, I was looking for a faster alternative to the math exp(x) function. I found something that suited me very well, most often this solution is called Ankerl algorithm. Refs :

https://github.com/ekmett/approximate/blob/master/cbits/fast.c
https://martin.ankerl.com/2012/01/25/optimized-approximative-pow-in-c-and-cpp/

There is typical Ankerl `exp` function implementation on C

```
double exp_fast(double a)
{
   union { double d; long long x; } u;
   u.x = (long long)(6497320848556798LL * a + 0x3fef127e83d16f12LL);
   return u.d;
}

int main()
{
   for (float x = 0; x < 10; x += 0.01)
      std::cout << x << '\t'
      << exp(x) << '\t'
      << exp_fast(x)
      << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I could not find a description of this algorithm. Perhaps in the literature it is called something else. I tried to plot this function and was very surprised - this is a piecewise linear approximation of the exponent function! It works perfectly in a very wide range of output values. All graphs contain about a thousand points (click to zoom)

[image]
[image]

I could not understand exactly how it works despite all efforts. It surprises me how such a simple code can give such good approximation. I will be very grateful if someone can clearly explain how this works and from what considerations the values `6497320848556798LL`, `0x3fef127e83d16f12LL` are chosen. And the second thing - is it safe to use such a solution or is it a sort of dirty hack which should be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

I think this algorithm is from the paper  [A Fast, Compact Approximation of the Exponential Function](https://nic.schraudolph.org/pubs/Schraudolph99.pdf) presented by Nicol N. Schraudolph.

The "Algorithm" section of the paper explains how it works. And the code presented there takes into account the endianess of the machine as well.

Comment: Thanks. It seems these algorithms use similar approaches. Im try to figure out with this

Comment: If the Ankerl mentioned in OP is same as the Ankerl who wrote this blog post: https://martin.ankerl.com/2007/02/11/optimized-exponential-functions-for-java/,   then it helps to note that he mentions the same paper in that blog post.